# Adding an empty line between first and second line in a text file

Tags: awk, sed

A file (foo.csv) contain entries (four columns) as follows:

```
A 5.3 3.2 1.2 
A 2.1 3.4 6.7
A 3.4 2.1 5.6 
A 0.4 2.2 4.2
```

In this file, I want to add the total number of lines in the first line followed by an empty line.

I want the output to be as follow.

```
4

A 5.3 3.2 1.2 
A 2.1 3.4 6.7
A 3.4 2.1 5.6 
A 0.4 2.2 4.2
```

Here is what I tried.

```
#to get the total number of lines in the file foo.csv
t=$((wc -l foo.csv | cut -d" " -f1))
#to add an empty line 
sed -i "1i\\" foo.csv
#to insert the total number at the top; this works fine.
sed -i "1i $t" foo.csv
```

I need to do this for a bunch of files. So, script will be useful. The problem seems to be in `sed -i "1i\\" foo.csv`. How to correct this?

Comment: Could you please add more realistic samples of input and expected output in your post as it is not clear.

Comment: This would do : `echo -e "$t\n\n$(cat foo.csv)"`, you should assign variable `t` as `t=$(wc -l < /path_of_file/foo.csv)`, no other `sed` commands required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file) 'FNR==1{print line ORS} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to add output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` to above code then.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file  ) '       ##Creating variable line whose value is bash command wc -l to get line count for Input_file as per OP request.
FNR==1{                                     ##Checking if line number is 1 here then do following.
  print line ORS                            ##Printing variable line here with ORS whose value is new line here.
}                                           ##Closing FNR block here.
1                                           ##awk works on method of pattern and action mentioning 1 making condition TRUE and no action will make print to happen.
'  Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

do the line counting with `awk` as well.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{next} FNR==1{print NR-1 ORS}1' file{,}
```

or, with `tac...tac`

```
$ tac file | awk '1; END{print ORS NR}' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite simply using `sed` with the `0,addr2` form (see `man sed` under *"Addresses"*) with general substitution, e.g.

```
$ sed '0,/^/s/^/4\n\n/' file
4

A 5.3 3.2 1.2
A 2.1 3.4 6.7
A 3.4 2.1 5.6
A 0.4 2.2 4.2
```

The `sed` expression simply finds the first occurrence of the beginning of the line `0,/^/` and then substitutes the beginning of the line with `4\n\n`, using `s/^/4\n\n/`

Add the `-i` option to edit-in-place (or `-i.bak` to create a back of the original (e.g. `file.bak`) while editing in place.

If you are interested in setting the number of lines, then you can simply get the lines with `wc -l` using *command substitution*, e.g.

```
$ sed "0,/^/s/^/$(wc -l <file2)\n\n/" file2
8

A 5.3 3.2 1.2
A 2.1 3.4 6.7
A 3.4 2.1 5.6
A 0.4 2.2 4.2
A 5.3 3.2 1.2
A 2.1 3.4 6.7
A 3.4 2.1 5.6
A 0.4 2.2 4.2
```

(**note:** the use of double-quotes instead of single-quotes to allow expansion of the command substitution)

Comment: The number (for this file 4) may vary for each file. So, I need to use variable in 'sed'.

Comment: You can always use `wc -l` to get the number of lines -- I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '1e wc -l <file' -e '1H;1g' file
```

or to do everything in sed:

```
sed -e '1e sed "$=;d" file' -e '1H;1g' file
```

This uses the `e` command to evaluate unix commands. Normally this is done using the `e` flag to the `s` command, but it can be used following an address, as in this situation.

An alternative, using a pipe:

```
wc -l <file | sed '1G' - file
```

or:

```
sed '$=;d' file | sed '1G' - file
```

Use the result of a wc or sed command as the first input file.

On retrospect, the easiest solution (although not the most efficient):

```
sed 'H;$!d;=;x' file
```

Which slurps the file into the hold space and inserts the number of lines and a blank line before printing out the hold space.